# Popping single items off list using MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

I am trying to use an item in a list several times. The list is created from a names of directories using MSBuild extensions:

```
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.FindUnder TaskAction="FindDirectories" Recursive="false" Path="path\to\stuff\">
        <Output ItemName="AllFoundDirectories" TaskParameter="FoundItems"/>
    </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.FindUnder>
```

I wish to use each item within this list in different instances i.e.:

```
<Message Text="##teamcity[testStarted name='%(AllFoundDirectories.FileName)']"/>
<!-- do some stuff using %(AllFoundDirectories.FileName) here -->
<Message Text="##teamcity[testFinished name='%(AllFoundDirectories.FileName)' duration='test_duration_in_milliseconds']"/>
```

The problem I have is that everything in the list is being called the first time MSBuild see's the variable *%(AllFoundDirectories.FileName)*. Is there a way to get a single variable out of the list at a time and use it in various places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use target batching on a dependent target.

```
<Target Name="MakeDirectoryItems">
   <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.FindUnder
      TaskAction="FindDirectories"
      Recursive="false" Path="path\to\stuff\">
      <Output
         ItemName="AllFoundDirectories"
         TaskParameter="FoundItems"
         />
   </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.FindUnder>  
</Target>

<Target Name="UseDirectoryItemsInBatch"
   Outputs="%(AllFoundDirectories.Identity)">
   <!--
      while inside this target, the value of both @(AllFoundDirectories)
      and %(AllFoundDirectories.Meta) will be just the single item
      in each batch.
   -->
</Target>

<Target Name="Driver"
   DependsOnTargets="MakeDirectoryItems;UseDirectoryItemsInBatch">
</Target>
```

Comment: this msbuild extension may now be https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164293.aspx ..